# A simple discrete probability exercise

Tags: probability

```
In a school of 600 students, 360 are girls. There are 320 hockey players, 
of whom 200 are girls. Among the hockey players there are 28 goalkeepers, 
19 of them girls.
360girls.....240boys.....600 students
200girl hp...120boy hp...320 hockey players
19 girl gk.... 9boy gk....28 goalkeepers
---------------------
Find the probability that
(i) a student chosen at random is a girl:: 360/600
(ii) a girl chosen at random plays hockey:: 200/360
(iii) a hockey player chosen at random is a girl::200/320
(iv) a student chosen at random is a goalkeeper::28/600
(v) a goalkeeper chosen at random is a boy::9/28
(vi) a male hockey player chosen at random is a goalkeeper::9/120
(vii) a hockey player chosen at random is a male goalkeeper::9/320
(viii) two students chosen at random are both goalkeepers:: 28C2/600C2
(ix) two students chosen at random are a male goalkeeper and a female
goalkeeper::(9/240)(19/360)
(x) two students chosen at random are one boy and one girl.(1/240)(1/360)
```

For ix: my answer is 19/600 * 9/600. Why is this wrong? Its like 19 male goalkeepers out of total students and 9 female goalkeepers out of total students. But answer is (9/240)(19/360)

For x: my answer is 360/600 * 240/600. Why is this wrong? Its like 360 male goalkeepers out of total students and 240 female goalkeepers out of total students. But answer is 1/240*1/360.

Like for example for question viii, the answer is 28/600*27/599. So why in cases of ix and x, its not the same?
My logic doesnt seem wrong...can someone explain?

Comment: Netiher.  I figure it should be $\frac {19*9}{\frac {600*599}2}=\frac {19*9}{300*599}$

Comment: This is a terrible, uninformative title.  Please fix it.

Comment: Skimming your question (*there is a huge wall of text, with massive amounts of information and very specific numbers I don't care about*), it looks at a glance like both your and the "books"(?) answer are incorrect for (ix).  The "book's" answer would be the probability that when specifically selecting one male at random and one female at random that both happened to be goalkeepers (*and does not consider the possibility of having selected two males for instance or two females*).  Your answer is incorrect because you forgot to decrease the denominator and account for order.

Comment: (x) should be closer to $\frac12$ and is in fact $\frac{240}{600}\frac{360}{599}+\frac{360}{600}\frac{240}{599}$ or $\frac{240\times360}{{600 \choose 2}}\approx 0.4808$, twice your answer

Comment: Given the books answer to viii I'd so the answer to nine should be $\frac {9*19}{600 C 2}=\frac {19*9}{\frac {600*599}2}$

Comment: For (x) as well... the answer of $\frac{1}{360}\times\frac{1}{240}$ is the probability that when picking a random boy and a random girl (*and ignoring the possibility that we could have picked two boys or two girls*) the probability that the boy picked was very specifically Adam Adams and the girl picked was very specifically Betty Bush.  (*or equivalently some specifically named pair of boy and girl*).  It is not how I would interpret the question which would have been what the probability is that having picked two students that one was *any* boy and the other *any* girl in any order.

Comment: Glancing through the other answers as well, it looks like there are several other mistakes... many of which stemming from misinterpreting the sample space in question.  (ii) for instance, "What is the probability that a *girl chosen at random* plays hockey"... the denominator here should have been the number of girls, the numerator the number of girl hockey players, so $\frac{200}{360}$, not $\frac{200}{600}$ which is the probability that a *student chosen at random* is a girl hockey player.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, otherwise i would have gotten wrong answers. thanks alot